What is the difference between Pantheism and Atheism?
I was talking about pantheism, and my interlocutor asked me the difference between pantheism and atheism. I realized the difference is fragile if there is any.
My question lies in the difference between having a god that, if I understood correctly, is unconscious and not personal and "does not await anything at all from us" from no god. It just seems to me that the god of pantheism is the same thing that an atheist would call the universe. It just seems to be a difference in semantics.

Pantheis is god=universe. Atheism is no god at all.

See Pantheism

The definitions of each should be sufficient, so what's this question about, really?

All grand monisms have this problem: Materialism: Everything is matter; Idealism: Everything is mind; Panpsychism: Everything is consciousness.  If thats all we have then Nothing to stop you from saying: materialism = idealism = panpsychism.  Of course the devil is in the details which you havent supplied!!

I can't believe this question hasn't been asked before. There must be something wrong with the search function.

Mild edit to stave off closure. Be careful with "opinion solicitation', which is a no-no around here. If you haven't, I encourage you to read https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Obviously, it is NOT a "difference in semantics". Atheism is the idea that there is no god, either "personal" nor "cosmological", while Pantheism is a philosophical theory (Toland, Spinoza in Europe) that gives to god a role in the universe but does NOT recognize a distinct personal god, anthropomorphic or otherwise. What is common to both is that they are NOT religions.

I have a policy of not trying to define other people's use of religious terms for them, since their understanding of the word may differ considerably from mine, and whether it is a correct use of the word or not is secondary except for purely academic purposes. I think the real answer here is to ask the individual what they mean by the word. I cal myself a strong-agnostic theist, but I don't expect anybody to understand what I mean by that without also seeing my definition.

Suggesting the difference is fragile, if there is any, is your choice. It's for you to explain that and no, you didn't already.
Your question stumbles on the difference between having any god, or none. No definition of god matters.
It just seems to me that rather than your 'difference in semantics' the actual point stems from your not noticing, there cannot be a 'god of pantheism'

For the shortest possible answer see @Mauro’s comment and his link. The link starts

Pantheism is the philosophical and religious belief that reality, the
universe, and nature are identical to divinity or a supreme entity.
The physical universe is thus understood as an immanent deity, still
expanding and creating, which has existed since the beginning of time.

When reading this definition literally, the question comes up: If “reality = nature = divinity”, are these concepts actually synonyms?

Of course they are not, because they are used with a different connotation and emphasis: A pantheist does not give up the concept of a deity. He considers the universe as a divine object, but he does not consider it in a personal form like most religions consider their deities.

For an atheist the god-concept has no referent, it is fictitious like witches and other spirits. The atheist considers the universe or nature as a non-personal entity, he sees no need to introduce a god-concept. The atheist does not speak or pray to the universe.
Hence both the pantheist and the atheist does not consider the universe in a personal form, while the theist considers the universe in a personal form, which he can address by praying and praising.

Spinoza’s dictum “Deus sive Natura” is often considered as the genuine expression of a pantheistic worldview. Sometimes also Einstein is considered a follower of a pantheist worldview. But I am not sure how much Einstein’s pantheistic “religiosity” was only a façon de parler.



Your bold highlights in #1 and #2 don't appear to be highlighting the salient parts, because they are highlighting what you see as the same between pantheism and atheism, not a difference as the question asked.

@DanGetz I don't follow. 'non-personal' is the same as 'personal'?

@JimmyJames "does not consider ... personal" vs "considers ... non-personal" seem the same to me, unless I'm missing something. Your comment illustrates why I commented.

@DanGetz Sorry, I see now.  Perhaps there's a subtle distinction there.  Good point.

@JimmyJames I made an addition to clarify my statement about "personal" versus "non-personal" form.

To be fair, (as a firm atheist), I will on occasion talk to "the universe" or Karma or "if there is a guy upstairs"... but, I have zero expectations, and zero suspicions that any of the three exist in order to actually hear me.  Kinda like talking to one's self.

One requires belief in the existence of one or more supreme beings, the other believes there is no need for a supreme being to exist.

Trouble is, what pantheism believes in as the "supreme being", is something that atheists also believe in the existence of.  That's the point of the question, and something you have not addressed.

Not relevant. Catholics believe bread and wine is transubstantiated into Christ's flesh and blood. I also believe in bread and wine, but that does not make me a Catholic.

There is something odd here, which is that both you and the other explicit atheist who answered want to speak against the idea of believing in a god or anything vaguely related.  This reinforces my belief that modern atheism is something distinct that is not adequately expressed by the straightforward meaning of the word "atheist" that "the number of gods is zero".

@Brilliand How does "the number of gods is zero" not adequately express that they would disagree with the statement "the universe is god"? If an atheist agreed that the universe was god, then they could not agree that "the number of gods is zero". Unless they also claimed to not believe in the universe, which is the opposite of your claim in your first comment.

@JMac: The problem is that saying "the universe is god" is not really sensible under the usual definition of the word "god" (i.e. most people understand "god" to mean "personal god"), so the pantheist has to appeal to a more inclusive definition, which might make the statement so weak that it does not actually contradict the atheist's "the number of gods is zero" because of the different definitions involved. Any account of atheism vs. pantheism really needs to directly address that definition.

@Brilliand - I am not speaking for or against anything though I suspect you do not properly understand the atheist view point. I certainly do not believe the number of gods is zero, since if exist, they could come into or out of existence at any time, changing that number. Theists (by definition, believers in the existence of gods), all believe the supernatural exists, and takes a particular form, though few agree on what that form is. I am not saying theists are wrong, I am saying that as an atheist, I have no need for the supernatural to exist in any form.

@PaulSmith So many peculiar statements there... 1) You said that the number of gods might not be zero because of a hypothetical what if they exist.  2) You said you have "no need" for the supernatural to exist.  Facts aren't true because we need them to be.  [What kind of atheist is this, that allows for gods to exist and talks about facts in terms of what he needs?]

@Brilliand - you supplied an erroneous definition for something you clearly do not understand. I corrected you in terms I thought might help you. I was was wrong. When talking about gods, or the supernatural, facts are superfluous.

The difference is that a god is typically thought of as conscious and having volition. (These are, of course, inadequate concepts applied in an act of anthropomorphization, epitomized in the man with a beard sitting on a throne). People who think that the universe is a god likely consider it being conscious and having volition. I don't know whether they consider it having a beard though.
Atheists may or may not consider the universe as being alive. If they do, the distinction is blurry and devolves into a question of labeling, probably depending on whether they think the universe is conscious and has volition and a beard, because that would be god-like.
An example for a scientist who proposes that the universe may be "alive" at least in a wider sense is Lee Smolin who suggested an entire population of universes undergoing an evolution.

To be sure of my understanding, I looked up pantheism...

I am an atheist.  Disbeliever of all gods/deities.  (And personally you can toss in supernatural beings like sasquatch, vamps and ghosts).
How do I differ from a pantheist?
I dont suffer the need to have the word god be included in any of my thoughts and deliberations.
Pantheists seem unable to help themselves in this regard, rather like theists.
If the term "god" and all it might represent to some... were removed from human history and vocabulary... the life of an atheist would not change.
A pantheist seems to want something to exist... something athiests have no stake or suspicion of or curiosity about.  The word "god".
Atheists dont need the word "god" to exist.
Atheism isnt part of or related to any god-beliefs.
Doesnt make sense to twist words to try and paint/taint them with the beliefs of pantheists.
Atheism = no gods.  (There is a period there on purpose cause thats the whole deal... i might go back and delete all else)

I distrust making this about the word rather than about the meaning of the word.

substituting "God" in place of "the physical stuff that makes up the universe" is hardly a trustworthy substitution IMHO opinion, and created the issue.

That isn't actually part of pantheism, though.  It's something that was done by the people trying to force-fit pantheism into the "atheism, monotheism, polytheism" classification system.

If pantheism is not "as it is defined"... then what is pantheism?

Well, the simple answer is, "as experienced by its believers".  Definitions describe it in terms of an external categorization system, which does not make the definition false but does make it incomplete (and when you assume the definition is the whole of the thing, you draw wrong conclusions).

Here's a closer (but still incomplete) description of pantheism: "The belief that nature itself is conscious and alive, and therefore that consciousness of the whole is the highest authority governing itself".

@Brilliand I found this from McGill university... "Pantheism does not involve a belief in deities, spirits or any supernatural powers. Instead, Pantheists believe that what is divine is right here on earth; in fact, it is earth. Pantheism's central tenet is that the universe, the earth, and nature are divine and so they should be treated as sacred."... and thought "hey.. no god". But then I looked up "divine" and found it = of, from, or like God or a god... so it shore seems like the same flower by a different name. .. does the pantheist "?????" enitity or whatever have awareness and influence

This all reminds me of the old Lincoln quote: "Q: How many legs does a dog have, if you call the tail a leg? A: 4, because calling it a leg doesn't make it one." Does calling the universe God make it a god? Are they recovered theists trying to have their cake and eat it?

An atheist and a pantheist would both think of the universe in non-personal terms, but someone describing themselves as a pantheist would be likely to regard the universe as having some divine or quasi-divine qualities, either literally or metaphorically: life, volition, power, transcendence, worthiness of respect or possibly even some form of worship. There would be an aspect of emotional or non-rational relationality toward it, where feelings of awe and a sense that there is more going on than human beings know or can know would be important.
Someone describing themselves as an atheist would be likely to present a rationalistic and reductionist stance toward the universe. Often there is a tendency towards a liberationalist epistemology, a sense that certain ways of thinking or relating towards the universe constitute a psychological burden or constraint which they are engaged in freeing the self from. They will emphasize such concepts as Occam's Razor, empiricism and verifiability along with a sense that experiential / personalist approaches are a lower order of understanding, which might be deprecated with terms such as "mysticism" or "woo".

This seems like the best answer to me. It's about how they view their personal relationship with the universe.

I consider pantheism to not be mutually exclusive with polytheism, monotheism and atheism.  As an example, I would call myself a pantheistic polytheist, meaning: There are gods (a good many of them), but nature itself is a divinity above the gods.
So, each of the three answers to "how many distinct gods are there" can go either way on the question of whether nature itself is divine; up to and including "pantheistic atheism", the belief that there are no particular gods but nature itself is divine.
Of course, you might be wanting to know about some factual beliefs underlying this belief that "nature is divine"!  The respect for nature does not seem like enough, by itself.  So, what else to we have?

Modern Atheists, alone among all these variations of "theism", do not generally believe in magic or spirits.  They do not have to disbelieve in those things; but, by and large, they seem to disbelieve in those things.
Pantheism (with the belief in individual gods) can mean either the belief that nature is a divinity above the gods, or simply that is alive and full of magic.  So, we have another unspoken distinction there.  Once could equate this to the differences of opinion among atheists about whether nature is "above" or "below" humans.

So, what is the difference between "atheism" and "pantheism"?  A bunch of things that go unmentioned in the names, which are, as always, an oversimplification of what is really a loosely organized group of people with a great many beliefs in common.  (Much like how monotheism and polytheism are vastly different clusters of beliefs, far more than the simple statement about "how many gods there are" would imply.)

Pantheism makes certain claims about the nature of reality that do not seem to be necessarily involved in atheism, and atheists would in many cases reject.
Atheism is simply the belief that there is no God and that all definitions of God have no real-world referent. It stands in need of an explanation for the absence of God (mileage may vary depending on your epistemology), but it isn't itself an explanation of this absence.
Pantheism asserts, instead, that the world (or the object of experience) exists because God exists, and because the two are indistinguishable. If we take the most sophisticated form of pantheism, which I believe is Spinozism, this leads to other claims which an atheist is not necessarily committed to, like:

Nature is absolutely infinite;
Nature is absolutely free; and
Everything in nature is perfect.

And other rather weird claims like this which most atheists would not want to adopt, but which follow directly from saying nature is an absolutely infinite, self-caused, and all-powerful Being. It's certainly the case that pantheism is essentially atheistic from a classical theist perspective since it typically denies that God is good, that God has a will, or that God could have chosen not to create the world (since for a pantheist this would mean God chose not to create Himself, which all parties agree is impossible). But I think a consistent atheist would find it just as unappealing as classical theism, so I think the two are meaningfully distinct.
